# How can I get on the PHP side the values of my array, and insert them into my database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've send my array with jquery ajax to my file addServicesRequest.php and I don't know how to use the values of my array one by one in my sql insert request...

If somebody can help it'll be great! Thanks a lot in advance !

Here's my jquery code : (works well)

```
$('#addServices').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {chosenServices!chosenServices},
        url: "addServicesRequest.php"
    });
});
```

Here's my php : (addServicesRequest.php)

```
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . ('/connectDatabase.php');

/*foreach ($postTest as $service){
var_dump($_POST["service"]);
}*/

$insertServices = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO CHOSEN_SERVICES 
                        (id_user, id_service, status) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$insertServices->execute(array(
    "id_user" => $_SESSION['id'],
    "id_service" => $_POST['service'],
    "status" => "payed"
));
```

Comment: Can you show us a `var_dump($_POST);` please

Comment: Is this correct? `data: {chosenServices!chosenServices},`

Comment: it returns only the last value of the array $_POST

Comment: Also what is `chosenServices`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i've corrected it with data: {chosenServices:chosenServices}

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://ibb.co/CM7htY5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190724/discussion-between-pandad-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: You are passing a prameter called `chosenServices` but using `$_POST['service']` ?? Does not compute

Comment: PLease post THAT CODE as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it this way:

your php script:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
  $action = $_POST["action"];
  switch ($action) {
    case 'INS':
    if (isset($_POST["data"])) {
      $data = $_POST["data"];
      $insertServices = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO CHOSEN_SERVICES
        (id_user, id_service, status)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
        $insertServices->execute(array(
          "id_user" => $_SESSION['id'],
          "id_service" => $data['service'],
          "status" => "payed"
        ));
         $response = array("status"=> "success","message"=>"everything its okay");
        echo json_encode($response);
      }
      break;

    }//end switch
  }//endif
```

Where action is a command you want to do SLC, UPD, DEL etc and id is a parameter

then in your ajax:

```
var service = $("#yourelement").val();
    function insertServicePayment(service) {
        var data= {
                   service : service
                  };

       return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addServicesRequest.php",
            data: {data:data}
        })

    }
```

call it like this:

```
insertServicePayment(service).done(function(response){
var data=JSON.parse(response);
if (data != null) {
//fill your forms using your data or display a message
}
})
```

Hope it helps